# Laravel resource route doesn't display show in controller

Tags: laravel

According to the Laravel documentation:

> This single route declaration creates multiple routes to handle a
>   variety of actions on the resource. The generated controller will
>   already have methods stubbed for each of these actions, including
>   notes informing you of the HTTP verbs and URIs they handle.

In my route I have this:

```
Route::resource('admin/companies', 'CompaniesController');
```

In my controller I have index, create, store, show etc.
Specifically in show I have this:

```
public function show(Company $company)
{
    //
    dd('hi');
}
```

I would expect when I hit this route:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/companies/onecompany
```

for it to dd my response.  Instead I get a 404 error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This route `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/companies/onecompany` is not a valid route that triggers resource functions according to [Laravel documentaion](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

The right URL that will trigger the `show(Company $company)` function is:

```
//This route will extract the `id` column from the model and show the required record.
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/companies/{company}
or
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/companies/{id}
```

Try an existing record in your database;

```
//Assuming there is a record with an id of 1
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/companies/1
```

Answer (score 1):

cause of your problem seems related to [Route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#route-model-binding)
,try it with id in uri.

to see list of your application's routes: `php artisan route:list`